# Determining the provider of Location - Android

Tags: android, location-client

I am using `LocationClient` method to retrieve user's current location. It is working quite well, but sometimes it is not accurate for obvious reasons like (I am being inside , using WIFI etc). I would like to know if there is a determine what Location Provider is used to fetch the location. getProvider() returns "fused" regardless if I am in inside or outside. I just need to tell user that he is not getting accurate location probably because he is in inside. Even better, tell the user what Provider is used to fetch his location.

Comment: you can use the `getAccuracy` value to figure out if you have an accurate location or not.

Comment: @njzk2: Is there an algorithm or rule-of-thumb which can determine what was used to returned the location?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if provider is available using isProviderEnabled method:

```
        mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code is only checking whether those providers are enabled are not. My question is slightly different than your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for getting the list of location provider -

```
List<String> matchingProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();
for (String provider: matchingProviders) {
  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
  if (location != null) {
    float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    long time = location.getTime();

    if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
      bestResult = location;
      bestAccuracy = accuracy;
      bestTime = time;
    }
    else if (time < minTime && 
             bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime){
      bestResult = location;
      bestTime = time;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using something similar (Google Recommended way of getting Best Location). My question is slightly different :)